Why is a CALayer retained after I stop referencing it?
I've the impression that my CALayer is retained after being added as a sublayer until the end execution block, instead of until I stop referencing it.
The parent UIView is however released as soon as it is de-referenced as expected.
class DebugCALayer: CALayer {
  let id: String
  init(_ id: String) {
    self.id = id
    print("DebugCALayer init \(id)")
    super.init()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

  deinit { print("DebugCALayer deinit \(id)") }
}

class DebugUIView: UIView {
  private let id: String
  init(_ id: String) {
    print("DebugUIView init \(id)")
    self.id = id
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    layer.addSublayer(DebugCALayer(id))
  }

  required init?(coder _: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

  deinit { print("DebugUIView deinit \(id)") }
}

This can be tested with this code:

final class CALayerReleaseTests: XCTestCase {
  override func setUp() async throws {
    print("setup")
  }

  override func tearDown() {
    print("tear down")
  }

  func testBaseline() throws {
    for i in 0..<2 {
      _ = DebugUIView("\(i)")
    }
  }
}


which logs
setup
init DebugUIView 0
init DebugCALayer 0
deinit DebugUIView 0
init DebugUIView 1
init DebugCALayer 1
deinit DebugUIView 1
tear down
deinit DebugCALayer 1
deinit DebugCALayer 0

The release cycle for the UIView is as expected, with instances being de-inititalized as soon as I am not referencing them.
However the CALayers remain referenced until after the test is teared-down.
If I now exit the main thread right after de-referencing my instance, the memory is deallocated correctly:
  func testDispatch() throws {
    for i in 0..<2 {
      _ = DebugUIView("\(i)")
      let exp = expectation(description: "")
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        exp.fulfill()
      }
      waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
    }
  }

logs
setup
init DebugUIView 0
init DebugCALayer 0
deinit DebugUIView 0
deinit DebugCALayer 0
init DebugUIView 1
init DebugCALayer 1
deinit DebugUIView 1
deinit DebugCALayer 1
tear down

My guess from those observations is that calling addSublayer has a retaining side effect on the layer that lasts until the end of the current execution block on the main thread. I was surprised to see this and was curious to understand what is exactly happening.
Note: running the same code in the Playground gives yet another result...

Some internal CoreAnimation stuff is retaining it. Use the memory graph debugger in Xcode to find out who is retaining it. You can also put a breakpoint in the deinit and use thread backtrace in lldb to see when it is deallocated.

Thanks. The memory graph was not useful to point to who was retaining it. A lot of obscure mallocs. I didn't know about thread backtrace, very useful!

From Sweeper's suggestion, I run thread backtrace from when the layer is de-initialized:
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00000001029267ec TestCALayerRelease`DebugCALayer.__deallocating_deinit(self=0x0000600000c64d50) at DebugViews.swift:20:11
    frame #1: 0x00000001029269dc TestCALayerRelease`@objc DebugCALayer.__deallocating_deinit at <compiler-generated>:0
    frame #2: 0x000000018a122644 QuartzCore`CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 28
    frame #3: 0x000000018a122d84 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 1384
    frame #4: 0x000000018a123f7c QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 68
    frame #5: 0x000000018040de34 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    frame #6: 0x0000000180408838 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 528
    frame #7: 0x0000000180408cf0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 968
    frame #8: 0x0000000180408514 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
    ...

This confirms that QuartzCore is retaining the layer until the end of the current run loop.
